# How to update several columns in PostgresQL table with a Go function

Tags: sql, postgresql, go

I use PostgresQL and Go. I have a table which is called `users`. I try to write a function which will be able to update several columns. This function takes column names and user object (type struct). Can you help me with this?

This is a User struct in Go:

```
type User struct {
  ID          int       json:"id"
  Username    string    json:"username"
  Password    string    json:"password"
  FirstName   string    json:"first_name"
  LastName    string    json:"last_name"
  Email       string    json:"email"
}
```

This is SQL script which creates users table:

```
create table "users"
(
  id                       serial       not null
  constraint user_pk
  primary key,
  username                 varchar(64)  not null,
  password                 varchar(128) not null,
  first_name               varchar(64)  not null,
  last_name                varchar(64)  not null,
  email                    varchar(64)  not null
);
```

1st example: I can pass `first_name` & `last_name` + full User object (postgres should update only these 2 fields)

2nd example: I can pass `first_name` & `email` & `username` + full User object (postgres should update only these 3 fields)

I have tried to do it with map but I could not:

```
func UpdateUser(db *sql.DB, m map[string]interface{}) (*User, error) {
  for key, value := range m {

  }

  err := db.QueryRow(UPDATE "users" SET ())
}
```

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far and what issues you've had?

Comment: @Adrian, question updated

Comment: The problem is that I do not know what and how many fields postgres should update

Comment: If you're receiving the list of fields to update, then you do know what and how many fields to update, right?

Comment: @Adrian, yeah, you're right:) I mean that I can pass 1, 2, 3, 4 ... values. It is dynamically

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/hNWjSeNgmt7

Comment: @mkopriva, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Use UPDATE
In the example i assume you have written the function, which takes variables. Lets assume the variables are:

- firstName
- lastName

The SQL code is as follows:

```
UPDATE users
SET first_name = firstName, last_name= lastName
WHERE [condition]
```

You may find that you need to write a class for this with an overloaded constructor so that it takes any number of variables that you want.

Or better still write a function for each of the rows:

```
UPDATE users
SET first_name = firstName
WHERE [condition] 

UPDATE users
SET last_name= lastName
WHERE [condition]
```

etc. It just means that the user will have to enter the items one at a time.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

Comment: There will be a lot of queries to database if you will write one function for one field

Comment: "write a class for this with an overloaded constructor" what? Go doesn't have classes, overloading, nor constructors.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my user update func:

I pass a User struct to the function and don't worry about which fields need to be updated, I just update them all. The caller is working with a User they got from a previous func that returned it from the DB (I'll show you the API handler if you want to see that).

After the update I call the `Get` function to get the freshly updated record from the DB and return the User struct. This is for certainty that the caller can see precisely what they just did.

```
// Update a User identified by id
func (u *UserModel) Update(user *models.User) (*models.User, error) {
    stmt := `UPDATE user SET
            first_name = ?,
            last_name = ?,
            email = ?,
            phone = ?,
            status_id = ?
        WHERE id = ?`

    var userStatus models.UserStatus
    userStatusID := userStatus.GetID(user.Status)

    _, err := u.DB.Exec(stmt, user.FirstName, user.LastName, user.Email, user.Phone, userStatusID, user.ID)
    if err != nil {
        if mysqlErr, ok := err.(*mysql.MySQLError); ok {
            if mysqlErr.Number == 1062 && strings.Contains(mysqlErr.Message, "uk_user_email") {
                return nil, models.ErrDuplicateEmail
            }
        }
        return nil, err
    }

    user, err = u.Get(int(user.ID))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return user, nil
}
```